# Query to get available dates using start and end date

Tags: elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I’m trying to create a query which returns available products with no reservation at that date (or date range) or no reservations at all. It’s driving me crazy.

Here is my current mapping with index settings:

```
{
  "development_product_instances" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "product_instance" : {
        "properties" : {
          "reservations" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "end_date" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
              },
              "start_date" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1503327829680",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "9b9BhF-ITta2dlCKRLrnfA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2040499"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers" : { }
  }
}
```

And the query:

```
  {
    bool: {
      should: [
        {
          nested: {
            path: "reservations",
            filter: {
              bool: {
                must_not: [
                  {
                    range:
                      {
                        "reservations.start_date":
                         {
                           gte: start_date,
                           lte: end_date
                         }
                      }
                  },
                  {
                    range:
                      {
                        "reservations.end_date":
                         {
                           gte: start_date,
                           lt: end_date
                         }
                      }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          not: {
            nested: {
              path: "reservations",
              filter: {
                match_all: {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

When there is more than one reservation it returns all.

I hope someone can see the bug in there. Maybe i'm missing something in the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `must_not` is inside the `nested` query. That means that if it matches for **any** of the nested reservations, then the parent document matches. So when there are multiple reservations, unless the range you're querying overlaps **all** the existing reservations, you get a match.  You can rewrite it like this (note that this query also matches when reservations is empty):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "reservations",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "reservations.start_date": {
                      "gte": start_date,
                      "lt": end_date
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "reservations.end_date": {
                      "gte": start_date,
                      "lt": end_date
                    }
                  }
                }, 
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "range": {
                           "reservations.start_date": {
                             "lt": start_date
                           }
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "range": {
                           "reservations.end_date": {
                             "gt": end_date
                           }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  } 
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i just realized that if i have a reservation from lets say 2017-09-10 to 2017-09-12 and i query for availability from 2017-09-11 to 2017-09-11 it says its available (aka. there is no reservation) but there is one. any ideas? basically i need the equivalent of SQL: WHERE start_date <= [ENDDATE] AND end_date >= [STARTDATE] right?

Comment: You're right, sorry about that! I've updated the answer for that case. I suspect there's a more concise query for this -- I'll update again if I think of it.